# boot or loading,startup,safemode

Tags: hard-drive, system-restore

My Samsung (NP365E5C-S02UB) will not load or start up and is stuck on the black screen. How can I get it to start, or how can I restore it back to the way it was before, or how can I get it to just load up without having to use a recovery disk or a usb flash drive recovery? Isn't there some buttons I can press on the keyboard other than <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd> to restart system or help it boot? Or is there some button combinations to do a factory reset? If I do a factory reset, will that erase my operating system?

Comment: Please indicate what operating system you are using.

Comment: I am afraid that there isn't a switch combination for that...